# Does closing a window reduce a serious risk of harm due to ball lightning?

Tags: weather, lightning

In my country, there is a popular belief that during a thunderstorm, windows should be closed because of the risk of ball lightning.

The answers to [this other question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2603/4383) explain that ball lightning “is a well-documented phenomenon”. Although, I can't find any statistics showing how often a ball lightning occurs, nor how many people were actually killed by it *when being inside*.

There is also [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5962/4383) which talks about the slight risk that open windows present in a context of an ordinary lightning striking an object inside the house, but ball lightning is not mentioned.

Is it an actual risk to leave windows open during a thunderstorm **in a context of ball lightning**? How big is the risk of being killed or injured by a ball lightning entering the house (especially compared to the risk of being hit by a car when crossing the road ?

Comment: Just outta interest, what country is this?

Comment: @MikeyMouse: France. It seems that the same belief exists in Belgium and Russia as well.

Comment: There is at least one reported case from 1944 of ball lightning making a hole in a closed window [in Swedish](http://www.hvi.uu.se/Lightning/blixtar/Klotblixt.html) and [with Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?sl=sv&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hvi.uu.se%2FLightning%2Fblixtar%2FKlotblixt.html&edit-text=).  But in any case it seems that ball lightning is rare and so it might be difficult to claim there was a serious risk either way.